# What is a thin loop?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, general-relativity, loop-spaces, holonomy

I read one definition of a thin loop: $\gamma$ is a thin loop if there exists a homotopy of $\gamma$ to the trivial loop with the image of the homotopy lying entirely within the image of $\gamma$.

Because a homotopy is a continuous map, I guess an example of a thin loop might be as following:

$\gamma(t)=\left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
\sigma(2t), & t\in[0,1/2)\\
\sigma(2-2t), &t\in[1/2,1]
\end{array}\right.$

where $\sigma(t)$ is any continuous curve.

Are there any other examples?

---

At the same time, two loops $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ are called thinly equivalent if $\gamma_1\circ \gamma_2^{-1}$ is a thin loop. So by this definition, I expect that if $\gamma_1\circ \gamma_2^{-1}$, $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ must be thin. This does not sound correct, but I cannot image other possibilities.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that your example of a thin loop is the only example (except maybe up to reparametrization). I will try and add a proof later if you like. The point about the thinly equivalent definition is that each $\gamma_i$ may not be nullhomotopic, whereas $\gamma_i \circ \gamma_2^{-1}$ could be and further it could be thin.

Answer (score 0):

To add to my comment above. In general, it is clear that a map $f$ is homotopic to a constant map with homotopy inside its own image if and only if the image of $f$ is contractible.  Therefore, for this case a loop $\gamma\colon S^1\rightarrow X$ is a thin loop if any only if its image is contractible.  Therefore it must of the form you have already stated (up to some scaling say), otherwise the image of $\gamma$ would be homotopy equivalent to a circle which is not contractible.

Comment: This is not true. Let $X$ be $S^1$ and $\gamma$ be a surjective map of degree zero. Then $\gamma$ is null-homotopic but (because its image is all of $S^1$) the homotopy does not leave its image, hence is thin. But $S^1$ is not contractible.

Comment: I think West talked about the image of $\gamma$ is contractible, instead of $X$. So his claim is correct to me.